Cant import xarray file
I am having a problem, where python cant seem to find to find t file that is in the same folder as the Jupiter notebook. I have tried copying the whole address, but it doesn't work.
I have recently switched computer, where it worked on the old computer, but on the new it doesn't work. I get the following error message:
KeyError: [<class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Dataset'>, ('c:\\Users\\rasmu\\OneDrive\\Skrivebord\\1 Python fysik\\3. år\\PUK\\Dataset.nc',), 'r', (('clobber', True), ('diskless', False), ('format', 'NETCDF4'), ('persist', False)), '3c8f0647-26f8-41da-8245-aec6e4ddd30c']

and
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\\Users\\rasmu\\OneDrive\\Skrivebord\\1 Python fysik\\3. år\\PUK\\Dataset.nc'

I only have this line of code:
    data = xr.open_dataset('Dataset.nc')


Problem solved, for some reason it couldn't handle a å in this computer

Interesting! What operating system?

maybe explicitly enabling UTF-8 support helps, as described here for instance.

Operating system is windows 11. However i believe the problem is because i have set my language to english, which before was in danish
